# incrementing timer in windows phone

Tags: c#, timer, windows-phone

I am having problems with making a Timer App on Windows phone.
I have the text box set to 00:00:00 and im trying to increment it every second but after the first second it wont do any more. I am sure it is an easy fix and would be very appreciative of any help. Thank you

> public MainPage()
>           {
>               InitializeComponent();

```
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;
        timer.Start();
    }

    void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        txtTimer.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }

    private void btnStartClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();

        timer.Tick +=
            delegate(object s, EventArgs args)
            {
                TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(0);
                time += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);                   
                this.timenow.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);
            };


        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); 
        timer.Start();

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried debugging your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
            TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(0);
            time += TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);                   
            this.timenow.Text = string.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", time.Hours, time.Minutes, time.Seconds);
```

The `time` variable is created each time the timer ticks. Thus each time you add one second to zero time span. You need to extract it from the delegate. Normally you would make it a class field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So i have to extract it above from the delegate so it will keep adding one rather than starting again? How would i go about doing this. Sorry its probably very easy but i am only starting off

Comment: Just add `TimeSpan time;` in the class (not in any of the functions). In the `btnStartClick` add `time = new TimeSpan(0);` before starting the timer. Remove the first line of the code I've copied to the answer (first line of the delegate).